# Unix: create a directory with the same name as the working directory

Tags: shell, unix, mkdir

Let's say I was in `/var/www/foo` and I wanted to create `/tmp/foo`. Is there a way I can do that programmatically and end up with a command like `mkdir /tmp/[insert something here]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir /tmp/`basename $(pwd)`
```

(Note that they are backticks, not forward ticks.)

This works because the backticks do command substitution.  It basically runs the stuff in the backticks and replaces it with standard out of the command run.  In this case the `basename` command with the current working path. And `$(…)` does exactly the same as the backticks.

The `basename` command "strip directory and suffix from filenames".  (see http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?basename)

You could also use (if you didn't want to have the backticks):

```
mkdir /tmp/$(basename $(pwd))
```

Note that if the path to the current directory contains spaces or other special characters, you need to put the command substitutions in double quotes:

```
mkdir "/tmp/$(basename "$(pwd)")"
```

Answer (score 0):

`$PWD` always contains the full path to the current directory. Hence `${PWD##*/}` (`$PWD` except the part up to the last `/`) is the name of the current directory.

```
mkdir "/tmp/${PWD##*/}"
```

You can leave out the double quotes if you know that the name of the current directory doesn't contain any whitespace or any of the characters `*?\[`.

In zsh, there is a simpler way of extracting the last component of a path:

```
mkdir -- /tmp/$PWD:t
```